# alternate colour rows in dynamically generated divs

Tags: css

I am trying to create some CSS that would make alternate rows in a div. My div rows are dynamic depending on the result of a query.

I know how to do this if I were using a table structure but I want to move away from tables.

I have read a number of ways on how this can be done but all the examples use a hard coded structure.

My HTML structure is:

```
<div id="wrapper-new">
<?php if(empty($row_fids['Flight'] )){ ?>
<div align="center"><img src="images/awaiting.gif" border="0" /></div>

<?php }elseif(!empty($row_fids['Flight'])) { 
 do { ?>

<div id="record-section">
<div id="time-section">
<?php print date("H:i", strtotime($row_fids['ScheduleTime']));?>
</div>
<div id="flight-number-section">
<?php print $row_fids['Flight']; ?>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
<img src="../../../../<?php echo $row_fids['AirlineLogoUrlPng']; ?>">
</div>
<div id="airport-name">
<?php print $row_fids['AirportName'];?>
</div>
<div id="temp-section">
<?php if(!empty($row_fids['TemperatureC'])) { echo   $_row_fids['TemperatureC']." &deg;C"; }?>
</div>
<div id="remarks-section">
<?php print $row_fids['RemarksWithTime']; ?>
</div>
<div id="terminal-section">
<?php print $row_fids['Terminal']; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
} while ($row_fids = mysql_fetch_assoc($fids)); 
}
?>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
#wrapper-new {
    width: 100%;
}

#record-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #CCC;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: inherit;
}

#head-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: inherit;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#topline {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #000033;
}
#temp-section {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #FC0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10%;
}
#time-section {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    color: #333;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10%;
}
#remarks-section {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    color: #FC0;
    width: 25%;
}

#flight-number-section {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    color: #FC0;
    width: 10%;
}
.responsive img {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 100%;

}
#airport-name {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    color: #333;
    width: 25%;
}
#terminal-section {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    color: #333;
    width: 10%;
}

#time-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #006;
    padding-left: 5px;
}



#board-header {
    display: inline-block;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 60%;
}
#board-header-text {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #006;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 25%;
}



#logo-image-section {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 20%;
    float: right;
}
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on how best to resolve this problem.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a table? You are *tabulating* data.

Comment: @Andy G I am trying to move away from tables and code just using div's. Are you saying this can't be done using just div's?

Comment: No, it can be done, but tables are designed to display tabulated data. People are encouraged to avoid *tables for layout* but many people misinterpret this to mean 'avoid tables altogether'.

Comment: Canyou post HTML code ? (Not PHP code)

Comment: If I'm interpreting his code correctly, `#record-section` is repeating, in which case so are all of his ids..

Comment: You are also using the deprecated (since PHP 5.5) mysql extension library, which has been removed from PHP 7. (And the obsolete align attribute.)

Comment: @Andy G thankyou, I know I am using mysql and not mysqli. I will address that in due course.

Comment: @Pat I will change the id's to classes.

Comment: @Andy G with the id's changed to clasees as pointed out by Pat, could you point me in the right direction on how this could be done without using a table, but with a dynamic div.

Comment: Supposing you had six classes that represent six columns. I think you could use odd and even, as posted answers demonstrate, to alternate colours on all odd and even instances of the class-names. You'd need 12 CSS rules. As requested, you should post the resultant HTML, not the PHP. This will make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: @Andy G Ok I take that onboard. I will sit and think this through. I want to avoid using a table if I can. I will get back. Many thanks, you have given me a lot to think on.

Comment: Scrub that, it doesn't require 12 rules. I've posted a demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstration using divs. There doesn't need to be a class on each "cell", just on the containing div that represents a row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
.table {
    width: 300px;
}
.table span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}
.row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
        <span>stuff</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: alternating divs]

Comment: many thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for. Your the man.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? It would help if you shared your html structure.

```
div:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-child(even){
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I have included the HTML and the CSS in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to alternate the color of divs based on your jsfiddle I would recommend doing something like this.

```
#record-section > div:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color:red;
}
```

The odd can also be replaced with even if you want to alternate the opposite columns.

Here's a linke to the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lur51cgt/).

Comment: hi and many thanks for the reply. The fiddle update you works but it gives alternate columns. What I am looking for is alternate colours on the div rows which are dynamically generated from a query to a data table.